# How to get the available languages of the current web of SharePoint from webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom

> fuction getLanguage(){ var context =new SP.ClientContext(hostUrl);
>       var web = context.get_web();
>       context.load(web); context.executeQueryAsync(
>                   function (sender, args) {
>                       var lcid = web.get_language(); },   function (sender, args) {  }); }

[image]

Comment: I can get the default language by this code but I want the alternate language. Does anyone know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: if you want the web's available languages you have to load the property SupportedUILanguageIds which will give you that.
Here is a link to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850901.aspx)
If you want the user's languages you have to get the SPS-MUILanguages from the user profile.
Here is some documentation on how the user profile api works [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800.aspx)
Hope that helps.

Comment: This is user profile language, which you choose in setting of profile. But i'm looking for current language which site has.

Comment: Do you mean the languages enabled on the current web site?

Comment: exactly. If you go to site setting--> language setting--> alternate laguage you can choose. This is i'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, my bad I didn't understand properly what you were talking about. I edited my answer to better answer your question. I also edited the title of your question to be more explicit.

Comment: Do you mind making my answer as the answer so people with the same question will know it?